# Scrolling Effect inside a group and group contains control in live code

Tags: livecode

I put a button, label and an image in a group. I made 5 copies of that group. I want to make it scrollable . How can I do this? I cannot use a list field or a data grid field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to scroll your groups by enabling the horizontal and vertical scrollbars via the groups property inspector.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to arrange your five groups in some manner and then group them all. Then your scrollbars can hopefully do what you need. It will be the arranging that makes your display move the way you want to, or not.